# Keras - Concatenating two inputs of same 1st and 3rd dimension but differing 2nd dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm creating a functional API keras model to regress and predict a numerical value based on two mixed-data inputs.

The network consists of two models, the outputs of which are intended to be concatenated and input into another model, which will output the final value to be compared against the value to predict.

My (unfinished) code looks like this:

```
def categorical_model():
    inputA = Input(shape=(3, 1329, ))
    x = Dense(8, activation='relu')(inputA)
    x = Dense(4, activation='relu')(x)
    return Model(inputs=inputA, outputs=x)

def continuous_model():
    inputB = Input(shape=(1329, 2))
    y = Dense(64, activation="relu")(inputB)
    y = Dense(32, activation="relu")(y)
    y = Dense(4, activation="relu")(y)
    return Model(inputs=inputB, outputs=y)

cat = categorical_model()
con = continuous_model()

catcon_list = [cat.output, con.output]
concatenated = concatenate(catcon_list, axis=0, name = 'concatenate')

concatenated = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(concatenated)

merged =  Model(input=[cat.input,
                    con.input],
             output=concatenated)

merged.summary()
```

The code results in a `ValueError` as such:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 3, 4), (None, 1329, 4)]
```

Can these inputs be concatenated? How can I change the axis to the 2nd dimension?

Comment: what is the shape of your data?

Comment: A=(3,1329, ), B=(1329, ) @MarcoCerliani

Comment: could you transpose A in (1329,3,)?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
concatenated = Concatenate(axis=1)(catcon_list)

merged = Model([cat.input,
                con.input],
               concatenated)
```

Comment: This code results in a TypeError: ```TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input')``` in line 102 ```merged =  Model(input=[cat.input,```

Comment: there is another error: you are calling Model with 'input' instead of 'inputs' - see my edits